# Is there a way I can display the first half of a for each loop and the other half later?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

How can I display half the rows inside a for each loop now and the rest later?
The for each loop will print 6 rows so I want to print the first 3 now and 4-6 later.

I tried using a while loop but it didn't work, tried placing it inside and 3 duplicates of same row.

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 3) {
foreach ($items as $res) {
    $image = $res['image_name'];
    $id = $res['id'];
    //echo '<img src="/e-com/images/'.$image.'" />'; ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $res['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['item_name']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo "£ ".$res['price']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $res['category']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $res['date_added']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/e-com/index.php/product/to_edit/$id'   >Edit</a>";     ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm(\"$id\"); return false'>Delete</a>"; ?></td>
</tr>

    <?php $i++;
    } }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$first = array();
$second = array();
foreach ($items as $i => $res) {
    $image = $res['image_name'];
    $id = $res['id'];
    $html = "
<tr>
    <td>".$res['id']."</td>
    <td>".$res['item_name']."</td>
    <td>£ ".$res['price']."</td>
    <td>".$res['category']."</td>
    <td>".$res['date_added']."</td>
    <td><a href='http://localhost/e-com/index.php/product/to_edit/".$id."'   >Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm(".$id."); return false'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>";
    if($i < 3) {
      $first[] = $html;
    } else {
      $second[] = $html;
   }
 }

echo implode("", $first); 

///few lines below

echo implode("", $second);
```

Comment: ok, but I'm having a problem with this line     <td> <img src="/e-com/images/".$image. "/> </td>

Comment: @AziebAssres I don't see that line on your original code, but I'm guesing the problem is with the double quotes around the src value. just change it to:  <td> <img src=\"/e-com/images/".$image. "\"/> </td>

Answer (score 0):

Check out `array_slice()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as an option. You can pull out the first three elements of `$items` into their own array, process them alone, and then pull out the last three at some other point and process them.